# How to select the Most Recent or last record from MySQL table using SQL syntax

Tags: mysql

How can I select Most Recent or Last 100 records from MySQL query?

I have 18 Millions of records in database. I want to select 100 most recent records by using `Timestamp` column but it takes more than 2 minutes to run.

Any other way to find the latest records without using `Order By`?

```
SELECT DISTINCT (dd.TIMESTAMP)
    ,dd.Amplitude
    ,pd.PatientId
FROM DeviceDetails dd
INNER JOIN DeviceSession ds ON ds.DeviceSessionID = dd.ByDevSessionId
INNER JOIN PatientSession ps ON ps.PatientSessionId = ds.ByPatientSessionId
INNER JOIN PatientDetails pd ON pd.PatientDetailsId = ps.ByPatientId
WHERE pd.HospitalPatientId = 'Rorys Test Ward Test Bed 2 @ 2015-07-31 18:36:41'
    AND dd.TIMESTAMP < '2015-08-04 11:53:08.962'
ORDER BY dd.TIMESTAMP
Limit 100
```

Comment: Distinct is costly, try to remove it. and apply the index against joins to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

try explain in order to see the execution plan. or run the following query.

```
explain  SELECT DISTINCT(dd.Timestamp), dd.Amplitude , pd.PatientId   FROM DeviceDetails dd   JOIN DeviceSession ds 
     ON ds.DeviceSessionID = dd.ByDevSessionId  
     JOIN PatientSession ps ON ps.PatientSessionId = ds.ByPatientSessionId   
     JOIN PatientDetails pd ON pd.PatientDetailsId = ps.ByPatientId   
     WHERE   pd.HospitalPatientId = 'Rorys Test Ward Test Bed 2 @ 2015-07-31 18:36:41'
     AND dd.Timestamp < '2015-08-04 11:53:08.962'       
     ORDER BY dd.Timestamp   
     Limit 100
```

about explain you can see the tutorial here.
http://www.slideshare.net/phpcodemonkey/mysql-explain-explained

Comment: Not the sol. of your problem but hopefully will give you direction.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it's a good idea to use some kind of aggregate function if you have repeating records that can be `grouped` together. Also, your `order by` statement is sorting the `Timestamp` field in ascending order, whereas in order to get the latest records, you would want to sort it in descending order using keyword `desc` explicitly. Even better option would be if you have a primary key or auto-incrementing field in your `DeviceDetails` table, then you could easily sort on that field as well. But for now, here is what I would do:

```
SELECT
     dd.TIMESTAMP
    ,max(dd.Amplitude)
    ,max(pd.PatientId)
FROM DeviceDetails dd
INNER JOIN DeviceSession ds ON ds.DeviceSessionID = dd.ByDevSessionId
INNER JOIN PatientSession ps ON ps.PatientSessionId = ds.ByPatientSessionId
INNER JOIN PatientDetails pd ON pd.PatientDetailsId = ps.ByPatientId
WHERE pd.HospitalPatientId = 'Rorys Test Ward Test Bed 2 @ 2015-07-31 18:36:41'
    AND dd.TIMESTAMP < '2015-08-04 11:53:08.962'
GROUP BY dd.TIMESTAMP
ORDER BY dd.TIMESTAMP desc
Limit 100
```